# shell script for chmod file name but only on new files since last run of the script

Tags: shell, scripting, chmod

i have a directory where new files are uploaded and receive numeric filename as they are uploaded. the file name is numbers that go up.

i need to change permissions for the file but only on new files that were uploaded since the last chmod.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When doing the each chmod action, touch a file, e.g. `touch /tmp/foo`.

When the next iteration comes around, use find -newer, e.g. `find . -newer /tmp/foo -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and then `touch /tmp/foo`.

Comment: And there you go @ashwin mehta. Nice one steve :)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to achieve this, you need to compare the "ctime" of the files
with the "atime" of the script. This cannot be done by a vanilla find(1) implementation but only by an extended find.

With a modern find(1) implementation like the BSD find or sfind, you may use -newerXY, in your case:

find . -newerca script

and this will find all files with a status change after the last read on "script".

Beware that some Linux distros by default mount filesystems with -noatime.